# Rectangle with oval bottom shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to create a flat oval that is as round as the example below?

[image]

I've looked at several examples on how to create the oval itself using CSS from the following sources:

- http://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/
- http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/1/

Unfortunately, as you size it down in height the oval just doesn't want to retain the rounded shape. Here is my current code on how I'm trying to achieve the same visual look as the image above:

*HTML*

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#">
<span class="text">Home</span>
<span class="oval"></span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```
a {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px 0px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: red; color: #fff;
}
.text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.oval {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px; left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%; height: 20px;
    border-radius: ~"20px/10px"; /* I'm using LESS and it requires ~"" to make it work */
    background-color: red;
}
```

[image]

---

As a thank you for everyone here and as help for anyone in the future, here is my final code:

*HTML*

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```
a {
        overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 30px 20px 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;

    &:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
            top: 0; left: -25%; bottom: 4px;
            z-index:-1;
        width: 150%;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
        background-color: #AECE33;
            border: 3px solid #6B6A65; border-top: 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a **responsive** version of this shape using a pseudo element to minimize markup :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nx030er2/)**

Output :

[image: Round bottom menu item]

*HTML :*

```
<div>Home</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
div {
    position:relative;
    width:40%; height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:10px auto;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1.8em;text-transform:uppercase;line-height:90px;color:#fff;
}
div:before {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:-25%; bottom:4px;
    width: 150%;
    background-color: #AECE33;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100%;
    border:4px solid #6B6A65;
    border-top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so very much my friend! And without any additional elements too... this is scary good :O

Answer (score 4):

[DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/618/)

```
.cover{ height:100px; width:300px; overflow:hidden;}
.set {
    background-color: #80C5A0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left:-50px;
    border-radius: 50% / 100%;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

<div class="cover">
    <div class="set"></div></div>
```

and this is what you want

[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/619/)

and for creating a fluid menu as you asked below use [**DEMO3**](http://jsfiddle.net/QGtzW/624/)

Comment: @himanshu Thank you, thank you a billion-zillion-bajillion times! :) This damn thing has driven me absolutely insane haha

Comment: @himanshu The example seems to only work with a fixed `width` for `.cover` and `.set`. The anchors in the `<ul>` will have dynamic widths mainly provided by the `padding`. I've tried altering the `width` on the example above but the moment I do the right side of the shape goes almost completely round :/

Comment: @adamj try using demo3

Answer (score 3):

Try this **CSS**

```
div {
background-color: #80C5A0;
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
-webkit-border-radius:  100% 100% 100% 100% / 0% 0% 100% 100%;
 border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100% / 0% 0% 100% 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/QGtzW/620/)

Comment: i think requirement of question is little different

Comment: @Vinod VT Thank you very much for your time and help! Even though the shape is round the corners aren't quite as right. But, I upvoted you because it came pretty damn close!